# Postgres String Array Comparison

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have an array of the form :

```
myArray = ["1234-56", "1234-567"]
```

My table has a column which is constructed exactly like the array and consists of a string array, we call the column : myColumn.

I want to output the rows where , one or more values of the arrays match.

My current attempt was the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn && myArray;
```

But this ends with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Column "56" does not exist.
```

Comment: It seems you are not passing the array constant properly from within your code. What are you using? Java? C++? C#? Please **[edit]** your question and add the code that runs your query.

Comment: The Array comes from JavaScript. The Code that runs my query is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string in double quotes is an “identifier” in SQL, that is the name of a table, column, function or other object.

So when you write

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn && ARRAY["56","95"];
```

PostgreSQL will identify `"56"` as a column name (it couldn't be a table in that context), and it complaint that table `mytable` has no column called `56`.

The solution is to mark `56` as a *string literal*, that is, surround it with **single quotes**:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn && ARRAY['56','95'];
```